# Reading and detect string from a column of matrix

Tags: string, matlab, matrix

I have a column of strings in a matrix

```
X = ['apple1 (15%)'; 'apple2 (15%)'; 'apple3 (15%)'; 'orange1 (15%)'; 'orange2 (15%)'; 'orange3 (15%)' ]
```

I need to create another column of matrix to redefine the content of X.

For example, I want MATLAB to redefine 'apple' as 1 and 'orange' as 2. So in the end I would expect something like this:

```
[1; 1; 1; 2; 2; 2]
```

However, the MATLAB could not read the string when I read the column of strings:

```
theMatrix = xlsread(myFile.xls);

for i = numTotalTrials;
 X = theMatrix(i,2)

> X = Nan
```

Further, I am using `strfind` to redefine the column:

```
t = strfind(X,'a');
if t == 1
    newColumn = 1
else
    newColumn = 2
end
```

Does MATLAB work this way? Thanks!

Comment: I have fixed the formatting of your question, but there are still syntax errors. Please double-check the code again. Also I'm still not sure I understand what you want to achieve, do you simply want to replace 'apples' with the number 1, 'oranges' with 2?

Comment: Have you tried using `regexp` or `regexprep`?

Comment: @BenA.: +1 I've posted a solution using regular expressions :)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using regular expressions:

```
%# note the use of cell-arrays
X = {'apple1 (15%)'; 'apple2 (15%)'; 'apple3 (15%)'; 
     'orange1 (15%)'; 'orange2 (15%)'; 'orange3 (15%)'};

%# match either apples or oranges
m = regexp(X, '^(apple|orange)', 'match', 'once');

%# which one was found
[~,loc] = ismember(m, {'apple','orange'})
```

The result:

```
>> loc
loc =
         1
         1
         1
         2
         2
         2
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know, if this is exaclty what you are looking for but starting with

```
X = ['apple1 (15%)'; 'apple2 (15%)'; 'apple3 (15%)'; 
     'orange1 (15%)'; 'orange2 (15%)'; 'orange3 (15%)'];
```

I would define an output vector `result`, loop over the input and just look for the
desired strings using `strfind` which might look like

```
result = zeros(size(X, 1), 1);
for row = 1 : size(X, 1)
    if ~isempty(strfind(X(row,:), 'apple'))
        result(row) = 1;
    elseif ~isempty(strfind(X(row,:), 'orange'))
        result(row) = 2;
    end
end
```

This will return

```
result = [1; 1; 1; 2; 2; 2];
```